# Throw different error than net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED from OncePerRequestFilter ( Java + Spring )

Tags: java, spring, httpresponse, httpconnection

I have an option to upload file into my application
I have set a limit for file size using **springframework**

in my application Context  file

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
   class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- max upload size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="41943040" /> <!-- 40MB -->
        <!-- max size of file in memory (in bytes) -->
    <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="1048576" /> <!-- 1MB -->

</bean>
```

I have a class called **CORSFilter** extending  **OncePerRequestFilter**

```
doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
 .... more code

catch(NestedServletException err){
            if(err.getRootCause() instanceof MaxUploadSizeExceededException) {
                        response.setStatus(418, StringUtil.getGson().toJson("File must be smaller than" +  " 40MB"));
                response.getWriter().flush();
                response.getWriter().close();
                throw err;
            }else {
                throw err;
            }
        }
```

Now if I inspect the response with a network traffic right after the close I know that the response having this status - but when I let it "Run" after the close
somewhere in spring the network error/status is being reset
and what I get eventually is **net:ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**

I have tried using this method

```
@ExceptionHandler(NestedServletException.class)
@ResponseBody
public UIException handleValidationException(NotValidException ve, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
    LOG.debug(ve.getMessage(), ve);
    return new UIException(ve);
}
```

But it didnt stopped there

Full stack trace attached:

```
    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MaxUploadSizeExceededException: Maximum upload size of 41943040 bytes exceeded; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (53990195) exceeds the configured maximum (41943040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:821)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1685)
    at com.amazonaws.xray.javax.servlet.AWSXRayServletFilter.doFilter(AWSXRayServletFilter.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
    at com.myCompany.web.filter.MultiReadServletFilter.doFilterInternal(MultiReadServletFilter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
    at com.myCompany.web.filter.CORSFilter.doFilterInternal(CORSFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
    at com.samaxes.filter.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1158)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1090)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.multipart.MaxUploadSizeExceededException: Maximum upload size of 41943040 bytes exceeded; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (53990195) exceeds the configured maximum (41943040)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1099)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:932)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (53990195) exceeds the configured maximum (41943040)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:965)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:310)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:334)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:115)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:158)
    ... 45 more
```

How can I get the error `(418/file size limit)` status on the network status 
response and not the **"ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"**

Comment: It's there at the top of the stack trace. You don't show, or even state, how you got the connection refusal, but presumably that was the result of an inappropriate retry. Solution: don't.

Comment: @EJP
The stack trace is from the Server logging - the client has no information what happens on the server.
I need this response on the client response - so he will know there is a limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-file-upload-and-connection-reset-issue/)

> If you try to upload a file size, which exceeded the size limit,
>   Tomcat will crop it at the default 2mb and reset the connection. To
>   solve it quickly, put a -1 (unlimited) for maxSwallowSize

Possible solution:

> 2. Idea
> 3. 1 Try to put a reasonable limit for the file upload, for example, 11mb (11 x 1024 x 1024 = bytes) in this example

```
Tomcat/conf/server.xml
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               maxSwallowSize="11534336" />
```

> 2.2 And implement a Javascript to check the file size before the upload.
>
> What about Jetty? Tested with Jetty 9, can’t find out any
>   maxSwallowSize setting, and it will NOT cause a connection reset if
>   the file size has exceeded the upload limit.